# How do i insert reply of text-message Twilio API php?

Tags: php, mysql, twilio

1) I get a text message from **Twilio API**.
2) Now i reply with the text-message from my device.

How can i insert that text-message which is send from my device.
It is Possible with Twilio PHP. ?

Comment: insert to database ?

Comment: yes , i want to insert in mysql database.

Comment: Maybe this would be your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8608306/twilio-api-storing-replies-from-incoming-text-messages?rq=1

Comment: Are you asking how to save the SMS that was sent to your Twilio number?

Comment: okay let me explain , suppose , i send one message to my mobile number using Twillio SMS API. After that, from my cellphone i m send reply back to for same message ,which one message i reply back, that **message** and **mobile number** will be store in to my database. these is the scenario. how's it is ?

Comment: How is it now, what happens when you reply? Do you get a message back?